# Prove that $ \lim_\limits{x \to a}\sin(x)=\sin(a)$

Tags: real-analysis

In epsilon delta terms:

For $\varepsilon > 0$ such $\delta$ exists, that $|f(x) - A| < \varepsilon \iff |x - a| < \delta $

$$|\sin(x) - \sin(a)| < \varepsilon$$
$$ 2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+a}{2}\right)\right| <  \varepsilon$$

What can I do next to continue proof? Use system of equations and bound each term by $\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$?

Comment: Use MVT or $|\sin(X)|\ leq|X|$ and $|\cos(X)|\leq1$.

Comment: In general, it is probably more advantageous to prove that for any continuous function you may switch the limit and the function. That is, roughly speaking $$f(x) \ \text{is continuous} \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(\lim_{x\to a}x).$$

Then if you demonstrate a function's continuity, the result immediately follows.

Comment: Do you have a definition of the sin function? Can you say first that the unit circle is a continuous relation that is split into 4 continuous functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$2\left| \sin { \left( \frac { x-a }{ 2 }  \right)  } \cos { \left( \frac { x+a }{ 2 }  \right)  }  \right| <2\left| \sin { \left( \frac { x-a }{ 2 }  \right)  }  \right| <2\left| \frac { x-a }{ 2 }  \right| =\left| x-a \right| $$

Answer (score 2):

Choose $\delta=\epsilon$, and we have $|\sin(x)-\sin(a)|\leq|x-a|$.

You can prove it using Taylor's expansion.

Comment: is there any other way to prove it other than taylor expansion?

Comment: You can study $g(x)=sinx-sina-(x-a)$, derive it

Comment: Taylor expansion or calculus implies that you already know that $\sin$ is differentiable. OP is trying to prove it continuous :)